# Instance Level Abstractions in C

Tags: c, unit-testing, design-patterns, function-pointers, instance-variables

I am not a C expert. I haven't done any C since my CS1 & 2 days in college. I have done a little C++ here and there but it's been a while. So what I'm asking about is the correct *pattern* to solve a problem I am perceiving.

I have decided to take on a fairly ambitious challenge and I am doing it in C. One of the things I am (re)learning is the different abstraction techniques in C vs. the ones I am used to having in higher level languages. The problem I am encountering, and asking about, specifically has to do with testing and functions.

For example, I have two functions `f` and `g` and `f` will call `g` if certain conditions are true.

```
void f(object* obj) {
  // ...
  if(obj->state)
    g(obj);
  // ...
}
```

I need to verify that `g` is actually being called but I also don't want to actually execute it, since it can do all sorts of other things. This would normally be solved in a higher level language by means of interfaces or abstract classes or inheritance. But in C I don't have these techniques.

In fact the only solution to this problem that I can think of is to utilize function pointers. Instead of calling `g` directly I think I should add a pointer to `object` such that it has a pointer to `g`, which I can replace with a pointer to a different function in tests.

```
typedef struct object {
  int state;
  void (*g)(object* obj);
} object;

void f(object* obj) {
  // ...
  if(obj->state)
    obj->g(obj);
  // ...
}
```

Then normally I just point to `g` when allocating an instance of `g` but in my test I point obj->g to a different function, one that merely verifies the incoming values and notes that it was actually called.

This is the idea I am having right now but I'm not sure if it's quite the correct C-ish way to solve this problem. Hopefully my description illustrates the problem I am encountering but what I am really wondering is how best to handle it.

What are the recommended design patterns for solving this problem in C?

Comment: What do you mean when you say you need to verify g is being called, but you don't want to execute it? Do you mean that sometimes you're going to run in some kind of test mode, and then you want to run some alternate version of g?

Comment: yes exactly. The real g can be quite complicated and what it does doesn't really matter for the purposes of testing f. I don't want to have to run all of what is in g just to test f. You would use interfaces and stubbing if you were going to solve this in C# for example.

Comment: I ended up actually not doing any of the below answers. Instead I created a custom malloc which I then insert a small header to each memory allocation (in debug only) which includes a "kind" enum value. I then created a new structure that has the same structure plus the desired hash value. When in debug mode I look at the header, detect the kind of structure coming in and either do the hash like usual or just use the provided hash if it exists. Works like a charm and has no runtime effects in release!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change the function `g` called in different calls of `f`, maybe you should pass in `g` as a parameter to `f`:

```
typedef void (*gFunc)(object* obj);

void f(object *obj, gFunc g) {
    ...
    if (obj->state) {
        g(obj);
    }
    ...
}
```

If you didn't want to mess up the function signature of `f`, you can define a version of `f` to call the above implementation:

```
void gNormal(object* obj);           //normal implementation of g
void gTest(object* obj);             //test version of g

void fGeneral(object* obj, gFunc g); //general implementation of f as above

void fNormal(object* obj)            
{
    fGeneral(obj, &gNormal);         //use the default version of g
}
```

Whether you choose this method or to make the function pointer `g` a member of the object is probably about the same from the language's point of view - you need to consider what makes more sense for your object structure.

Then again, if you are doing lots of stuff like this, maybe you should be using an object-oriented language!

Comment: Yes I see. This would definitely work. You said "... consider what makes more sense for your object structure". I think either way would work I'm just wondering if there is some standard practice that is recommended. The common way to handle it so to speak.

And with regards to using an object-oriented language... that's what I'm trying to make :) You gotta start somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

If you know at compile time whether you want to be in the testing case, you can have two different implementations of g that are controlled via preprocessor macros, so something like:

```
#ifdef TESTING

    int g() { // implement test version here }

#else

    int g() { // implement real version here }

#endif
```

If you only know at compile time, you could give use a global variable in the same way, but with both implementations in the same function definition:

```
 int g() {
     if (gTesting) {
         // implement test version here
     }
     else {
         // implement real version here
     }
 }
```

Comment: I'm not sure the macro solution will quite work since I also have other tests for g elsewhere. I actually need real-g to exist I just don't want to always call it. The other solution would work but that kind of thing can get really ugly really fast.

Comment: I don't know if it will work any better for your code, but you could also move the macros to inside of f, so that within f, you call the real g if TESTING is not defined and the test version of g if TESTING is defined.